# Elements into view animation add class, animation

Tags: jquery, css, animation, scroll, scrollview

I tried implement event when element into view, and make some css animation. 
When user scroll to this element, the circle and text should grown. I use jQuery, how to make it with pure js. Also should change font-size in span. If I'll be use the same function for the several elements how to make it globally. I need professional advice here for the correct implementation. Thanks.

[codepen](http://codepen.io/palaniichukdmytro/pen/WoOMYB?editors=1010)

```
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorem et, nisi culpa enim distinctio neque libero minus nam. Sint tenetur eaque quidem ducimus ipsum, nostrum. In asperiores minus quisquam, nihil sunt ab praesentium alias neque error eveniet laudantium assumenda ex dolore fuga voluptas ipsa id quos hic ea qui corrupti architecto quo incidunt. Tempora quaerat quae officia cum aspernatur aliquid reiciendis cupiditate obcaecati nisi delectus sapiente quis laboriosam excepturi, ad, eius quia numquam culpa id perspiciatis doloribus tempore. Quo est, quidem quasi illo eius quas dolorum, debitis perferendis possimus temporibus accusamus error, earum quis dolorem maiores, distinctio necessitatibus labore numquam. Ipsam accusamus molestias atque voluptatibus nemo ipsa, accusantium neque asperiores ex cupiditate dolorem similique quas maiores, illum praesentium architecto soluta aliquid est voluptate vitae deleniti! Perferendis esse facere, in. Tenetur totam expedita, reiciendis quibusdam nisi iusto, aperiam. Obcaecati rem nobis commodi, esse temporibus vero, veritatis fuga ad repudiandae, officia inventore maxime possimus quos ab reiciendis illum quia voluptates dignissimos id soluta dolores. Odio facere libero quidem perspiciatis et ut! Delectus, at error officia! Ducimus eum, consequatur voluptate harum iusto, perferendis totam, repellendus nesciunt unde soluta cumque maxime rem aspernatur recusandae enim minima modi possimus, explicabo quos consequuntur commodi eligendi sunt.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorem et, nisi culpa enim distinctio neque libero minus nam. Sint tenetur eaque quidem ducimus ipsum, nostrum. In asperiores minus quisquam, nihil sunt ab praesentium alias neque error eveniet laudantium assumenda ex dolore fuga voluptas ipsa id quos hic ea qui corrupti architecto quo incidunt. Tempora quaerat quae officia cum aspernatur aliquid reiciendis cupiditate obcaecati nisi delectus sapiente quis laboriosam excepturi, ad, eius quia numquam culpa id perspiciatis doloribus tempore. Quo est, quidem quasi illo eius quas dolorum, debitis perferendis possimus temporibus accusamus error, earum quis dolorem maiores, distinctio necessitatibus labore numquam. Ipsam accusamus molestias atque voluptatibus nemo ipsa, accusantium neque asperiores ex cupiditate dolorem similique quas maiores, illum praesentium architecto soluta aliquid est voluptate vitae deleniti! Perferendis esse facere, in. Tenetur totam expedita, reiciendis quibusdam nisi iusto, aperiam. Obcaecati rem nobis commodi, esse temporibus vero, veritatis fuga ad repudiandae, officia inventore maxime possimus quos ab reiciendis illum quia voluptates dignissimos id soluta dolores. Odio facere libero quidem perspiciatis et ut! Delectus, at error officia! Ducimus eum, consequatur voluptate harum iusto, perferendis totam, repellendus nesciunt unde soluta cumque maxime rem aspernatur recusandae enim minima modi possimus, explicabo quos consequuntur commodi eligendi sunt.</div>
 <div class="flex">
  <div class="item">
  <span>9</span>
 </div>
 <p>Text here</p>

 <div class="item">
  <span>8</span>
 </div>
 <p>Text here</p>

 <div class="item">
  <span>1</span>
 </div>
 <p>Text here</p>

<div class="item">
 <span>10</span>
</div>
<p>Text here</p>
```

```
<script>

// Returns true if the specified element has been scrolled into the viewport
function isElementInViewport(elem) {
  var $elem = $(elem);

// Get the scroll position of the page.
var scrollElem = ((navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('webkit') != -1) ? 'body' : 'html');
var viewportTop = $(scrollElem).scrollTop();
var viewportBottom = viewportTop + $(window).height();

// Get the position of the element on the page.
var elemTop = Math.round( $elem.offset().top );
var elemBottom = elemTop + $elem.height();

return ((elemTop < viewportBottom) && (elemBottom > viewportTop));
}

// Check if it's time to start the animation.
function checkAnimation() {
 var $elem = $('.flex .item');

// If the animation has already been started
if ($elem.hasClass('grow-js')) return;

if (isElementInViewport($elem)) {
    // Start the animation
    $elem.addClass('grow-js');
  }
}

// Capture scroll events
  $(window).scroll(function(){
    checkAnimation();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution here [codepen](http://codepen.io/palaniichukdmytro/pen/WoOMYB?editors=0110)

```
.flex {
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
  position: relative;

.item {
position: relative;
width: 5rem;
height: 5rem;
background: yellow;
border-radius:50%;
transform: scale(0);
&.grow-js{
transform: scale(1);
  -webkit-animation: eighty 2s ease-out forwards;
   -moz-animation: eighty 2s ease-out forwards;
    -ms-animation: eighty 2s ease-out forwards;
     -o-animation: eighty 2s ease-out forwards;
        animation: eighty 2s ease-out forwards;
 }

 span  {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  font-size:5px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
}
 p  {
  margin-left: 10px;
 }
}

@-moz-keyframes eighty {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0);
 }

100% {
    transform: scale(1);

 }
}

@-webkit-keyframes eighty {
  0% {
     transform: scale(0);
 }

 100% {
    transform: scale(1);
 }
 }
```